# How to use case when in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I use case when in MySQL like this:

```
select name, age, time, countDay, dvt, total, dateLogin, 
 (total - datediff(NOW(), dateLogin)) as totalVal18,
 (total - age) as totalVal22
    case dvt 
        when dvt = 0 then countDay = totalVal18
        when dvt = 1 then countDay = totalVal22
```

Update 1:

Struct table is: `dvt, total, countDay` is `double` type.

`dateLogin` is `datetime` type.

User input is `dateLogin` and `age`.
Output using `countDay` to check values. Like:

`where countDay >= 18`.

`dvt` is `tinyint`. `dvt` like your `age > 18` or `age < 18`

Error like:
error like `case dvt 
        when dvt = 0 then at line 2`

When using formula it happens error? How to using the formula in `case when` MySQL?

Comment: You can use sub query to get the datediff value

Comment: Can you show us sample input and output so that we may help with your query?

Comment: Will you please show your table SQL query so that we can make query for you

Comment: Always include the error in the question.

Comment: I was updated my question.

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad: error like `case dvt 
        when dvt = 0 then at line 2`. I think this error is not important.

Comment: Instead of `case dvt when dvt = 0 then....` use `case when dvt = 0 then...`

Comment: I was update like your comment and still error

Comment: what is your table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly combined the 2 versions of the case structure.

Either use

```
case dvt 
    when 0 then totalVal18
    when 1 then totalVal22
end as countDay
```

Or

```
case
    when dvt = 0 then totalVal18
    when dvt = 1 then totalVal22
end as countDay
```

forms. See [mysql's documentation on case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Update

You cannot use column aliases this way, you need to include the formula in the case statement as well.

Comment: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case
    when dvt = 0 then totalVal18
    when dvt = 1 then' at line 2`
This still show this error.

Comment: Missing comma after `totalVal22` in the original query @fds.

Answer (score 1):

Check  this Sample Here table refers to your table name

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN dvt > 18 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS 
countDay
FROM table
```